# How do I access attributes of an html element on server side using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ejs, body-parser

```
<button name="myButton" value="someValue" data-value="someDataValue">Click me! </button>
```

How do I use server-side javascript to access the button's `data-value`? I only know how to use body-parser to access `value` by writing `req.body.myButton`.

Comment: I dont think you can. In ejs, I used to change the props passed to ejs file but I don't think it is possible to use js to dynamically modify   client-side  HTML dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. Only the `value` itself is posted by the browser. You can use client-side JavaScript to populate a hidden field with any extra information you need -- or to do the submission completely in JavaScript.